# Cannot connect to data source SSIS script task

Tags: ssis, script-task

I cannot seem to connect to the database connection i have set up in the SSIS package inside a script task. Here is my code it is a OleDB connection.

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        OleDbConnection myOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection();
        myOleDbConnection = (OleDbConnection)(Dts.Connections["Connection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as OleDbConnection);
        MessageBox.Show(myOleDbConnection.ConnectionString, "OleDB Connection");

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

I get the following exception

[image]

Comment: @EricHauenstein I totally believe SSIS contains every possible error message ever devised.

Comment: Apologies i have cleared up the question

Comment: @KyleHale Since it includes a transaction isolation level of "Chaos", I'm inclined to believe you.
Psycho, the image still does not appear to be loading for you.

Answer (score 0):

AcquireConnection() method of the connection manager returns a unmanaged Object, in your case of `Oledb` it returns native `COM object`. so use `Ado.net connection` if possible in your scenario.

If you want to stick to Oledb then here is a workaround.

```
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["Connection"];
IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams = cm.InnerObject as  
                                                      IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;
OleDbConnection myOleDbConnection = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;
```

Comment: For some reason, I am only getting null for cmParams.  Any Ideas why?